# Xamarin Forms - libvlcsharp fullscreen mode

Tags: libvlcsharp

Is there way to play video in fullscreen mode in Xamarin Forms with library - libvlcsharp ?

I'm connecting to ip camera, the view is fine but not in fullscreen.
I made code for double tap detection and now I'm looking for method to do it in fullscreen by this library

Answer (score 0):

Install LibVLCSharp.Forms 3.1.1-alpha, it contains a media player element with built-in support for multiple aspect ratios.

Will be released in LibVLCSharp.Forms stable soon.

Comment: Can U drop some code or give link to documentation ?

Comment: Try running https://code.videolan.org/videolan/LibVLCSharp/tree/feature/mediaelement-initial-setup/Samples/Forms/LibVLCSharp.Forms.MediaElement

Comment: Relevant code is https://code.videolan.org/videolan/LibVLCSharp/blob/feature/mediaelement-initial-setup/LibVLCSharp.Forms/Shared/PlaybackControls.xaml.cs#L808

Comment: I've got code foru running app, but I havent access to AspectRatio method, only Aspect

Comment: Will this code work? 
VideoView.MediaPlayer.Fullscreen = true;